# Return index value from nested json data

Tags: java, json

I need to find out for which data index qualify is true and return the company name of which qualify is true with index number of data.

I am able to find the index and if it is true but its not appropriate and I am not able to understand how would i return to other function.

Here is the sample approvec=

> {   "usecase": "OPs",   "annualFee": 60,   "data": {
>       "10017": {
>         "company": "Vodafone",
>         "qualify": true
>       },
>       "10035": {
>         "company": "Verizone",
>         "qualify": true
>       }   } }

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(approvec);
        JSONObject mnoMetadata = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                for (String mnoData: mnoMetadata.keySet()) {
                    JSONObject mnoMetadata1123=mnoMetadata.getJSONObject(mnoData);
                    boolean val=mnoMetadata1123.getBoolean("qualify");
                    System.out.println(val);
        }
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just giving it a try here. This code snippet returns a list of IDs that you can return whose qualify=true

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(approvec).getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray ids = jsonObject.names();
List < String > returnIds = new ArrayList < > ();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length(); i++) {
    String id = ids.getString(i);
    if (jsonObject.getJSONObject(id).getBoolean("qualify"))
        returnIds.add(id);
}

return returnIds;
```

Comment: Error shows- org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["usecase"] is not a JSONObject.